# Weka error - Premature end of line read Token[EOL], line 171.

Tags: weka, ioexception, eol, arff

I have red all the specifications for ARFF files and already implemented on my file still I cannot remove this error. 
I have the arff data content as follows:

```html
@RELATION face_features_ASM_usnig_all 

@ATTRIBUTE A1 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A2 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A3 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A4 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A5 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A6 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A7 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A8 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A9 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A10 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A11 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A12 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A13 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A14 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A15 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A16 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A17 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A18 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A19 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A20 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A21 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A22 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A23 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A24 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A25 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A26 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A27 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A28 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A29 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A30 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A31 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A32 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A33 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A34 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A35 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A36 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A37 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A38 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A39 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A40 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A41 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A42 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A43 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A44 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A45 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A46 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A47 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A48 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A49 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A50 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A51 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A52 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A53 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A54 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A55 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A56 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A57 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A58 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A59 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A60 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A61 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A62 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A63 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A64 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A65 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A66 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A67 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A68 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A69 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A70 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A71 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A72 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A73 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A74 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A75 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A76 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A77 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A78 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A79 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A80 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A81 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A82 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A83 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A84 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A85 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A86 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A87 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A88 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A89 REAL

@ATTRIBUTE A90 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A91 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A92 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A93 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A94 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A95 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A96 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A97 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A98 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A99 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE A100 REAL


@ATTRIBUTE class  {Person1,Person2,Person3,Person4,Person5}

@DATA

51.820,46.901,26.646,-53.556,31.995,2.435,7.748,-48.387,23.861,-75.401,-46.461,-42.062,-25.493,-52.391,-13.073,-63.624,-

49.200,23.057,-58.704,-62.997,-75.624,7.642,5.870,76.625,43.654,-0.859,-26.375,-0.915,-60.741,-16.781,14.860,1.729,-

17.014,26.867,35.407,2.523,-12.049,-28.276,18.744,-39.211,-42.997,28.665,-77.878,-26.688,-2.889,-89.605,-72.116,47.751,-

43.469,2.707,10.366,-52.120,-22.891,48.342,-2.071,-58.657,-16.388,24.407,-17.994,-80.313,33.966,29.153,-51.709,-

22.568,39.525,5.397,-26.314,-26.655,46.403,-85.413,-60.195,-10.727,6.769,-65.528,18.489,-25.848,31.052,-19.554,36.605,-18.419,-

63.856,54.886,-0.772,1.530,105.988,83.374,19.018,20.332,136.130,-23.827,-32.828,12.822,23.990,-10.836,-33.045,145.105,-

42.044,82.520,-46.695,94.547,Person1
```

All my data is labelled in the same format and it works for the other arff files.
I've checked Weka's example files, seems nothing different other than my attributes and data. Weka example files delimits data in a row from each other with commas and with pressing enter it passes to a new row.
Can somebody help me why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

After so many efforts I got the solution to this problem. I searched for unwanted commas and deleted them. Used NOTEPAD ++ to follow standard .arff model and saved the file with .arff extension. Then the error didn't occur.